# How to view and inspect a containerised 'Azure Function' deployed to Azure App Service Plan

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-container-registry

We have deployed the container (from VS Code) to an App Service Plan.
Our TestFunction is there but no Functions below it.
Does that suggest an issue ?

App Service Plan > Apps > TestFunction > **No Functions listed**

How do we access the container and inspect it ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can share the docs you followed to deploy the container through VS Code, it will be helpful to give the advice.

Comment: We followed a lot of the guidance we found online, such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-using-azure-container-registry  but I'm not sure if this is what we need.  In the ACR repository, we have 2 options:  'Run Instance'  or ''Deploy to web app'.  Where is the option to run the image for the Function App ?  We already deployed the Function App and its available in Azure. But there's a disconnect somewhere. The Function App is running but where's the container .. Perhaps we DO need to run it as a 'Container Instance'